# How to use the API KEY in google shopping

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-shopping-api

Im trying to execute a method of content API, so, when I test the follow URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/accounts/authinfo?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The call of the service retrieves me:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

But still show me the same error. Please any guide of this integration, I need call it from a C# console application, not by web site app with OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

You cant if you check the documentation for [Accounts: authinfo](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/accounts/authinfo)

it clearly states that you must be authenticated with the following scope

[image]

You will need to add Oauth2 and login.  The fact that you are using a service account does not change the fact that you must have permission to access private user data.  Api keys can only be used to access public data.   If you are only accessing your own account then you may want to consider using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/service-accounts)